# Video.js get event when any stream is downloaded in HLS videos

Tags: http-live-streaming, video.js

I want an event to be called whenever any file (m3u8 or ts) is downloaded by video.js.
Usecase is on the event of download file, I will map the file name with uuid of user and send to backend.
In this way, I will know which user has downloaded (or played) how much of video.

Please add comment if usecase is unclear, I will address th doubts.

Thanks in advance.